# Как заполнить LIst<int> числами вводимыми через textbox?(c#)

Tags: c#

Имеется List, в который через форму с textbox-ом надо ввести числа.Числа вводятся в textbox через пробел потом по нажатию нa button добавляются в List.
(c#).

функция для добавления элемента в List:

```
public void AddElement(List<int> l)
{
    try
    {
        l.Add(Convert.ToInt32(richTextBox1.Text));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Введенное значение не является числом");
    }
}
```

Она вызывается в событие кнопки button_click

Comment: а в чем сложность? просто по нажатию кнопки, сплитите текст, и результат конвертируете в нужный тип и добавляете в лист.

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: [пример](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/7.2.php) того как можно достичь желаемого

Comment: А как потом конвертировать ввод строки в число?

Comment: @atak23z для начала выложите код в котором обозначены ваши контролы и действие по нажатию кнопки (остальное ничего не нужно). Для того что-бы выложить код воспользуйтесь кнопкой править, под текстом вопроса.

Comment: @atak23z  для конвертирования строки в число, используйте класс Convert.

Comment: после *сплита* исходной строки, получится массив строк к экземплярам которого можно применить функцию конвертации, например `Convert.ToInt32(s)` где s исходная строка

Comment: Спасибо сейчас попробую так сделать

Answer (score 1):

тогда у вас должно получиться следующим образом

```
public void AddElement(List<int> l)
{
   var intElements =richTextBox1.Text.Split(' ');
   for(int i=0;i<intElements.Length; i++)
      {
   try
   {
      l.Add(Convert.ToInt32(intElements[i]));
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    MessageBox.Show("Элемент "+i+" - значение не является числом");
   }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Или так:

```
    public void AddElement(List<int> l)
    {
        var intElements = richTextBox1.Text.Split(' ');
        var numbers = intElements.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
        if (numbers == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Последовательность содержить недопустимые значения");
            return;
        }
        l.AddRange(numbers);
    }
```